# How to fix `failed to open stream: Too many open files error` in PHP

Tags: php, download, stream

I have a loop where I save some images locally, then move them to S3

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    // download image
    $stream = fopen($image['path'], 'wb');
    write($stream, $image['content']);
    fclose($stream);

    // copy to S3
    $manager->copy('local://' . $image['p'], 's3://' . $image['p']);
}
```

The problem is that I get a `failed to open stream: Too many open files error` error

Any ideas how can I avoid this?

```
Warning: include(/var/www/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files in /var/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter' not found in /var/www/vendor/symfony/monolog-bridge/Handler/ConsoleHandler.php:155
```

Comment: What is `$manager`?

Comment: It's the `Flysystem MountManager`. That part works.

Comment: If you comment this line (`$manager..`), the error still occurs?

Comment: Are you sure it's getting to the foreach? According to the error, it's coming from the class loader. Comment out the whole foreach and check.

Comment: @aynber The classloader loads classes when the are called. it is trying to open the  `'Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter'` to write some error log but is failing since flysystemm is keepin the file resources active

Comment: looking into it. thank you

Comment: This is an issue that was raised on the github page for flysystem a long while back here: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/issues/140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the `ulimit -n` or disable multipart uploading inside the aws-s3 driver for flysystem. it is flysystem that is keeping too much files open.

Ok a quick fix for you would be:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {

   $resourcesOpened = count(get_resources('stream'));

     while ( $resourcesOpened > 900 ) {
       sleep(10);
       $resourcesOpened = count(get_resources('stream'));
     }

     // download image
     $stream = fopen($image['path'], 'wb');
     write($stream, $image['content']);
     fclose($stream);

     // copy to S3
     $manager->copy('local://' . $image['p'], 's3://' . $image['p']);
   }


}
```

Comment: `ulimit -n` doesn't help. I might need to figure out how to make Flysystem close some of those files

Comment: you cann try to remove that part to make sure it is causing it. try commenting the copy line  out and see if the error continues

Comment: looks like it is the Flysystem

Comment: i think this will fix it for you. i typed it quick so pls forgive any mistypes in this i can edit this later on